# permalinks on title tag

Tags: permalinks, title

Is it possible to have my custom permalink structure on title tag of my blog?

my current permalink structure is this
`/%postname%/%location%/%mba_courses%/` where my location and mba_courses are custom taxonomies

Now I want this on my title tag, can I write something like this in title tag?

```
<title><?php echo (/%postname%/%location%/%mba_courses%/); ?><title>
```

I know this is a wrong code, and it won't work, but is their any way, where I can have this kind of title tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to cause your permalink structure to be reflected automatically in the title tag. Instead, you must create it yourself. This might get you started: (I had to make a lot of assumptions in this code.)

```
function my_title() {
    $post = get_queried_object();
    $locations = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'location' );
    $mba_courses = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'mba_courses' );
    $postname = $post->post_title;
    $location = $locations[0]->name;
    $mba_course = $mba_courses[0]->name;
    return "$postname | $location | $mba_course";
}
```

Then, in your single post template:

```
<title><?php echo my_title(); ?><title>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your not using an SEO plugin you can use wp_title to put the permalink url as the tile.

```
<title><?php wp_title(' '); ?></title>
```

Comment: sorry for the above comment, but this is not what I want,
My URL structure is in this way
MBA-IN-INSEAD(post-name)/MBA-IN-FRANCE(location)/MBA-IN-ACCOUNTS(course name)
In terms of SEO this is the best URL for an MBA website, so in same way I want it for my title tag, which should be something like this:
MBA IN INSEAD | MBA IN FRANCE | MBA-IN-ACCOUNTS

Comment: @ntechi I misunderstood your question.  I thought you wanted the url in the title tag.

Comment: its actually the URL's text, you are not completely wrong, but how can this be done?